# Is there a way to stay logged in to app after destruction for push notifications

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I'm working on an Android app that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for push notifications. Right now, I'm facing a challenge where users get automatically logged out when the app is closed or the device is restarted. How can I design my Android app to ensure that users remain logged in and continue to receive push notifications, similar to apps like Instagram or WhatsApp?

Answer:

Even after the app is destroyed or closed, Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) can still deliver push notifications to your device. FCM operates independently of the app's state, allowing your users to receive notifications seamlessly, whether the app is running, in the background, or completely closed. Like what Abu Bakar Mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `FirebaseMessagingService()` then it is gonna survive after reboot and get started automatically to receive the pending notifications. What I mean by pending is that if the device is offline for some time then the notifications can live in pending state for almost a month and if device gets online within that timespan then the notifications are delivered.

You can check the doc here [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)